# lista, max/min em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, algoritmo, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Olá, preciso fazer um algoritmo em python que leia um arquivo de texto *.csv* que contém literalmente 5 milhões de números e preciso que esse algoritmo me diga qual é o menor e qual é o maior número da lista.
Agora, os problemas:

Usei esse código para abrir a lista no python:

```
import csv 

lista = open('lista.csv', 'r') read: 
csv.reader(lista) 

for linha in reader: 
    print (linha)
```

Ele funciona normal, mas para apresentar o maior e o menor, seria isso:

```
import csv 

lista = open('lista.csv', 'r') reader: 
csv.reader(lista) 

for linha in reader: 
    print linha 

    menor = min(linha) 
    maior = max(linha) 

    print (menor, maior)
```

O algoritmo funciona, o real problema é que aparece que o menor valor é *nulo* e o maior valor é **-83422495.2710933**

Nós já tentamos colocar separado (um algoritmo para maior número e um para o menor número) e não adianta, também já tentamos tirar o 'for' e não funciona...

queria saber se há outra forma de fazer ou em que estamos errando... desde já agredeço muito.

Comment: acho que faltou apenas um sample do csv para ver como estão arranjados os valores, se é um valor por linha e tem 5 milhões de linhas, ou são 5 milhões de numeros em uma linha?

Comment: São 9 ou 10 colunas com 5 milhões de linhas. Acredito que o programa esteja lendo todos os números

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido assim:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"-?\d+\.?\d*")

with open("C:/Users/lab2d/Downloads/lista2.txt") as f:
    numeros = pattern.findall(f.read())

numeros = [float(i) for i in numeros]

if numeros:
    print("Maior valor:", max(numeros))
    print("menor:", min(numeros))
```

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode usar o pandas, criei um exemplo com apenas 36 números aleatorios (3 linhas de 12 colunas) gerados de forma randomica para simular o seu `csv`, leio esse 'arquivo' para um objeto pandas DataFrame e depois apresento os valores mínimo e máximo.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

# Simulando o csv
lista = '''
6848, 8453, 6877, 3508, 2071, 1962, 7274, 4901, 9369, 3498, 2138, 2504, 9948
6543, 7021, 260, 2392, 648, 9947, 6759, 3553, 3437, 4121, 2637, 8067, 9421 
6609, 5229, 1872, 2288, 8448, 9701, 1256, 4489, 7549, 2844, 4561, 3291, 5472 
'''

# Lendo o csv
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(lista), header=None)

# Apresentando o resultado
print('Valor máximo:', df.values.max())
print('Valor mínimo:', df.values.min())
```

Saida:

```
Valor máximo: 9948
Valor mínimo: 260
```

**Obs.**
1. Parti do pressuposto que seu csv não tem cabeçalho para as colunas, se tiver retire o `header=None` do comando de leitura do csv.
2. Se quiser/precisar tem mais algumas funcoes como `sum()`, `mean()`, etc.

> Editada
>   Para testar a possibilidade de a quantidade de dados ser um problema, criei um exemplo onde crio um DataFrame com 6mi de numeros extraido de um array numpy gerado de forma randomica, depois apresento os valores minimo e máximo, e a média de todos os valores.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
qt = 6000000

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,qt,size=(1000000,6)))

print('Valor máximo:', df.values.max())
print('Valor minimo:', df.values.min())
print('Média dos valores:', df.values.mean())
```

Saida:

```
Valor máximo: 5999999
Valor minimo: 2
Média dos valores: 2999119.789572667
```

Mesmo sem o pandas, é possível extrair os valores máximo e mínimo diretamente de uma lista com 5mi de dados em python "puro":

```
lista = list(range(0, 5000000))
print('Máximo:',max(lista))
print('Mínimo:',min(lista))
```

Saída:

```
Máximo: 4999999
Mínimo: 0
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, eu e um amigo estamos trabalhando nisso, vamos pensar em uma maneira e volto para dizer se deu certo =)

Comment: A "maneira" é reproduzir na integra o meu codigo, se não der certo, provavelmente deve ter algum problema no seu csv.

Comment: O csv funciona normalmente, acredito que no meu código esteja dando erro devido a quantidade de números e o tamanho do arquivo.

Comment: Acho pouco provavel que seja esse o motivo, ja trabalhei em um projeto cientifico (reconhecimento de imagens) com dados muito maiores do que isso usando o pandas, sem problemas, vou editar a minha resposta dando um exemplo com 5mi de dados.

Comment: Para você entender melhor, aqui estão as primeiras linhas do arquivo:

4034502.7276325077, -48332085.46707194, 3039517.323714033, 34621956.41685204, 83558920.69945103, 60675521.97461882, -50771435.78885216, -18648336.730533928, 79937747.62000978, 79916178.6943368
-22290443.041666657, -68526627.05718894, 14971865.045767307, 44530748.08120343, -56745411.08461867, 80380542.97220108, -79189767.50952648, -5623825.827204466, 73029838.43669158,

Comment: Será que salvar o arquivo como texto, ajuda na questão das colunas e linhas?

Comment: Não é preciso, fiz um teste aqui, criei um csv (atraves do pandas, :-)) com 10 milhoes de numeros em 5 colunas, li atraves do pandas e extrai o minimo e o maximo, sem problemas. Vc ja testou meu código? Teve algum problema?

Comment: Como disse anteriormente, estou trabalhando com um amigo, veremos hoje de noite. Vamos ver se conseguimos com o teu código, espero que sim kkkk já estamos desanimados com tantos erros.

Comment: tentei com seu código mas preciso baixar a biblioteca pandas, e eu não consigo de jeito nenhum, tanto em pip quanto em Anaconda... decepcionada

Comment: Qual versao do python, anaconda? que erro ocorre?