# Listas Python Max Value

Tags: python

Tenho uma dúvida a respeito das listas em python.
Vamos supor que eu tenha uma `lista1`, com nome, loja e valor de vendas, eu tenho que retornar o nome da pessoa que mais vendeu.
exemplo:

```
vendedores= [{"nome": "Maria", "loja": 1, "valor": 100.00},
             {"nome": "João", "loja": 2, "valor": 110.00},
            ]
```

Como relacionar o maior valor com o nome do vendedor e retornar somente o nome da pessoa que mais vendeu?

Obrigada, desde já!

Comment: Na verdade vc tem uma lista de dicionários, nesse seu codigo, estude as listas e tb os dicionairios. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
valor,nome=float(0),""


 for i in vendedores:
       if i['valor']>valor:
          valor=i['valor']
          nome=i['nome']
print("vendedor {} :\nvalor: {}".format(nome,valor))
```

Answer (score 2):

A própria função `max` nativa do Python permite você definir qual será a regra para definir qual é o item de maior valor no seu iterável através do parâmetro `key`. No teu caso, basta achar o item que possui o maior campo `valor`, assim:

```py
vendeu_mais = max(vendedores, key=lambda vendedor: vendedor['valor'])

print(vendeu_mais['nome'])
```

Comment: Essa resposta que deveria ser marcada como correta.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Deve ser duplicata, só ainda não achei

Comment: Essa aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/367701/lista-max-min-em-python?rq=1 ?

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in vendedores:
       if i['valor']>valor:
          valor=i['valor']
          nome=i['nome']
print("vendedor {} :\nvalor: {}".format(nome,valor))
```

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/253701)

Comment: @TiedtTech, quando fizer a revisão tenha mais atenção nas mensagens que vincula com essa análise. Essa mensagem é destinada ao usuário que responde apenas com links. Minha impressão sobre a resposta é que mesmo ela sendo fraca ela ainda é uma tentativa concreta em solucionar o problema e eu(pessoalmente, você ou outro usuário podem discordar) entendo como tentativa de resposta válida.